# Google Chrome Developer Tools emulate drag and drop events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The question is simple, but can't really find an answer.

How to **simulate the drag & drop events** using chrome developer tools ?

sure i can manually drag & drop the file, but then i can't inspect the changes in DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simulate Drag & Drop events with the [jQuery Simulate library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate) and the [Drag & Drop extension](https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext/blob/master/doc/drag-n-drop.md) for it, which uses the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events to achieve it.

You can also use Event Listener Breakpoints to pause execution on certain events. With the library above, you could pause execution on those mouse events.

[image: Event Listener Breakpoints]

Answer (score 0):

You may drag and drop and observe the CSS class that gets activated.
For example, jquery ui uses ".ui-state-hover"

Then you can edit the HTML tag in the Developer tools to add the class **ui-state-hover** and it will show permanently as if you're dragging something over it.

```
<li class="ui-tree-droppoint ui-droppable ui-state-hover">
```